# images not showing

Tags: channel-entries

I can see the images in file manager but none of them are showing up on the site:

http://metlab-tec.net/

If I go the products page and try to add files to the media tab, nothing happens.

I didn't build the site and am not familiar with expression engine but would like to learn it.

Can anybody point me in the right direction - it would be most appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Images are not showing in backend channel entry ? or frontend?

Answer (score 0):

The site is also reporting CORS errors for the fonts from `http://metlab-tec.com` (which as a result appear to not be loading), so there may be issues related to how these two domains interact that are compounding your problems.

Fixing the images thing really depends on how images are being processed within your site's EE setup: but since the URLs for the images are missing rather than 'wrong' it suggests your media configuration is broken somehow: it might be (for example) that your file upload directories are pointing to a location that can no longer be accessed (or is empty).

If you let it be known which version of EE you are using (should appear in footer of Control Panel interface) and how your EE installation is accessing images (e.g. via native media handling or via an add-on such as Assets or Channel Images) there maybe more help that can be provided.

Comment: Thank you for replying to my question. I am a complete novice when it comes to EE so any help you can give would be much appreciated. I believe the site is running V2 & I seem to recall seeing something called 'assets'. I would be happy to give you access to the control panel and ftp access, if neccessary.

Many thanks

Comment: If you contact me directly (via jcogs.net) (or let me have contact details for you) I'll see what I can do to help.